# When I am trying to make release sign App Bundle getting below Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, bundle

> **A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:produceReleaseBundleIdeListingFile' (type'BundleIdeModelProducerTask').**
>
> > **File 'E:\E drive\myproject\release\app-release.aab' specified for property 'finalBundleFile' does not exist.****

**Android Studio Version : 4.2.2**

Below is my Gradle File>

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "com.bugsnag.android.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
def config = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext") // Created variable to access "ext"

android {
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        applicationId "com.wowfie"
        minSdkVersion config["minSdkVersion"]
        targetSdkVersion config["targetSdkVersion"]
        compileSdkVersion config["compileSdkVersion"]
        buildToolsVersion config["buildToolsVersion"]
        versionCode 68
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    bundle {
        density {
            enableSplit true
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit true
        }
        language {
            enableSplit false
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Anyone please help me out with this

Comment: Have you resolved this?